# VBA code for copying data multiple times on a new sheet depending on a cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I am very much new to VBA. I am trying to automate a copy function in a sheet I use daily.

What i want to do is copy the Name and ID the number of times as the count shows to a next sheet in column B and C. If the count is 0, the counter will move to the next row without copying the name and ID of that particular row.

```
Name   ID      Count
Dave   dg124s   8
Robert rc5675  10
Mary   mg987    0
John   jh785    6
June   fg71d   22
```

Challenge is

1. The number of row containing the data can exceed at any given time.(here we have 6 rows of data but can increase upto 40).
2. The copy should start from the bottom most row and go to top.(start from row 6 in this case)
3. While pasting, it should start from the top most row of the next sheet(Fields remain same in the next sheet)

Hope I have explained it clearly. I will be obliged if someone could help me on this.

Thanks,

Dave.

Comment: We understand that you are new to VBA but have you tried anything? Can you show us what have you tried and where r u stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

[EDITED]

```
Sub CopyNames()

Dim rngCopy As Range, rngTemp As Range, rngTarget As Range
Dim intMultiple As Integer, i As Integer, intRow As Integer

Set rngCopy = Sheet1.Range("A2", Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)) 'Set range including names
Set rngTarget = Sheet2.Cells(Sheet2.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) 'Set target range to next available row in Sheet2

For intRow = rngCopy.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
    Set rngTemp = rngCopy.Cells(intRow)
    intMultiple = rngTemp.Offset(0, 2) 'Find how many times to copy the name
        For i = 1 To intMultiple
            rngTarget.Value = rngTemp.Value 'Copy name
            rngTarget.Next.Value = rngTemp.Next.Value 'Copy ID
            Set rngTarget = rngTarget.Offset(1, 0) 'Move target range to next row
        Next
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Just checked the code and it works. Except I need to copy the bottommost row first. It pasted in the column A and B. I want to do it in B and C.                                                   Set rngTarget = Sheet2.Cells(Sheet2.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).....................Here before(sheet2.Rows....) if I specify the cell value from where it should start pasting will it work?........Thanks again!

Comment: OK - can you reverse the order on the first spreadsheet so the topmost row goes first? If not, we'll need to change the `For Each rngTemp` loop to step back through the range. I'll update the answer.